Why does FB SDK login with permissions gives UI issue? Like, buttons hide
My app allow users to integrate their FB account and users can manage their pages.
But when user try to connect and login modal opens by facebook. Then the continuer button at the bottom hides.
Using
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.1.0"
My code:
LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(FBPermissionsArray)
.then(
login => {
if (login?.isCancelled) {
console.log('Login cancelled');
                    setloading(false)
                    
                    showMessage({
                        message: "Facebook login cancelled",
                        duration: 5000,
                        statusBarHeight: 0,
                        titleStyle: { lineHeight: hp('2%'), fontSize: RFValue(14) },
                        type: 'warning'
                    })
                } else {
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
                        console.log('device token data>>>>>', data);

                        const accessToken = data?.accessToken.toString();
                        getInfoFromToken(accessToken, loaderValue);
                    });
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error);
                
                setloading(false)
                
                showMessage({
                    message: "Facebook login failed. Please try again",
                    duration: 5000,
                    statusBarHeight: 0,
                    titleStyle: { lineHeight: hp('2%'), fontSize: RFValue(14) },
                    type: 'warning'
                })
            },
        );

const FBPermissionsArray = [
'public_profile',
'pages_show_list',
'pages_manage_ads',
'pages_read_engagement',
'leads_retrieval',
'ads_management',
'pages_manage_metadata',
'business_management'
]
I tried to search this issue on internet but I found nothing. I tried to delete my app, disconnect FB account from app and again connect it but this issue still exist.
For now, the soultion is to delete FB app and when integrate with FB via my app. User needs to enter credentials in the modal (webview). Then in the webview, the buttons won't hide. But it's not a valid solution, why would user delete his/her FB app.
In the previous version of FB SDK, the buttons won't hide but the UI in the new version (that updates automatically) is disturbed.


